# Is every element contained in a Borel subalgebra?

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\frak g$ be a complex semisimple Lie algebra. Is every $X\in\frak g$ contained in some Borel subalgebra $\frak b$?

**Attempt:** I know that a Borel subalgebra is by definition a maximal solvable subalgebra. Now, $Span(X)$ is abelian so it is solvable. Hence $Span(X)$ is contained in a maximal solvable subalgebra.

I am not sure about the last part. Can we justify this?

Answer (score 1):

Every solvable subalgebra $S$ of $L$ is contained in some Borel subalgebra $B$ of $L$. This is the definition of a Borel subalgebra. Over the complex numbers all Borel subalgebras are conjugated.